# Ember.js data from a route does not show in template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

[image: as you can see, hbs has a placeholder for {{abcd}} and route returns the value for abcd but my page does not show that data. When i do a view source, i can see that js function is carried into the page! Am I missing something? do I need to write something in controller folder before route and model/template can talk to each other?]

as you can see, hbs has a placeholder for {{abcd}} and route returns the value for abcd but my page does not show that data. When i do a view source, i can see that js function is carried into the page! Am I missing something? do I need to write something in controller folder before route and model/template can talk to each other?

Comment: Templates don't know anything about route properties. `{{abcd}}` would refer to a **controller** property. PS. Don't paste pictures of code. Paste the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

Templates don't know anything about route properties. `{{abcd}}` would refer to a **controller** property. In order to access it you will have to go through the controller's model property `{{model.abcd}}`.

I would recommend you give the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/) a thorough look.

Comment: got it working, example did not provide the entry needed in controller folder...i had a strong hunch that controller must be in play to connect the pieces (facepalm!)

Comment: @TejasDamania it should be mentioned that if you don't create a controller explicit you still get one implicit generated for you.